# How to change OrientDB Studio timeout

Tags: orientdb

The `OrientDB Studio` (web interface) has a very short timeout before it wants you to log in again. Where can I change the timeout duration? Google did not help and searching through the config directory also came up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file `<orientdb_folder>/config/orientdb-server-config.xml` and add the following entries in the `<orient-server><properties>...</properties></orient-server>` section:

```
<entry value="9999999" name="network.http.sessionExpireTimeout"/>
<entry value="9999999" name="network.token.expireTimeout"/>
```

And restart the server. That worked for me.